# How to debug Lightning Chart datetime error?

Tags: lightningchart

I am currently using Lightning Chart in my Vue application. I create my chart as follows before mounting:

```
const createChart = () => {
  chart.value = lightningChart().ChartXY({container: `${chartId.value}`})
                        // .setBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#ffffff'), alpha: 100 }))
                        .setPadding({ left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5 })
                        .setTitleMarginBottom(0)
                        .setTitleMarginTop(0)
  // Set chart title
  chart.value.setTitle("Power Spectrum Density");
  chart.value.setTitleFont(new FontSettings({ size: 12, style: 'italic' }));




  // Set up axes
  chart.value.getDefaultAxisX()
          .setTitle("Time")
          .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#FFF') }))
          .setTitleFont(new FontSettings({ size: 12, style: 'italic' }))
------>>> .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime)  /*, (tickStrategy) => tickStrategy.setTimeOrigin(props.startTime)) */

  chart.value.getDefaultAxisY()
          .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#FFF') }))
          .setTitleFont(new FontSettings({ size: 12, style: 'italic' }))
          .setTitle("Frequency (Hz)")
          .setInterval(0, 750, false, true);
...
... 
    const spectrogramColumns = data.length;
    const spectrogramRows = data[0].length;
    const heatmapSeries = chart.value.addHeatmapGridSeries({
               columns: spectrogramColumns,
               rows: spectrogramRows,
               heatmapDataType: "intensity",
             })
              .setFillStyle(paletteFill);

            heatmapSeries.addIntensityValues({
            iRow: 0,
            iColumn: 0,
            values: data,
            })
    
}
```

However this results in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at n.t.$i (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at m (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at n.t.zn (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at n.t.On (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at n.Xu (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at eval (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at i.a.yT (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at i.Xu (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
    at i.eval [as rr] (lcjs.js?add5:1:1)
```

I am only recieving this error when **SetTickStrategy** is included, otherwise the chart is working as expected. Am I missing something that is required for the DateTime tick strategy?
Maybe worth noting:

- I have been using as a guide the interactive example at https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0021-dateTimeAxisOrigin.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light
- I have tried using TimeTickStrategy which gives the same result
- I am importing the necessary components

Comment: Using DateTimeTickStrategy shouldn't require anything extra so you should be safe there.
I'm not spotting anything strange in the code... Could you try to replicate the error with minimal code inside the Interactive Example editor? For example, using this link: https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0021-dateTimeAxisOrigin.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply Niilo. I believe the issue is to do with Vues reactive objects but I cant figure out the specifics. In this codepen I have a minimal version of my code with the same error: https://codepen.io/edsank/pen/ZEaZGbz, strangely everything else works using this setup **except**  the SetTickStrategy. I have found a hacky solution by converting it to a reactive state ( I want to update it live) after setting up the axes seen here https://codepen.io/edsank/pen/YzEMyoK.

Comment: Maybe you can also check the LCJS Vue template if it could inspire some kind of solution to this. The code seems to have somewhat different Vue syntax between these two.
https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-vue-template

Comment: This is the new syntax that Vue 3 have been subtly pushing which they called the ''composition API", I did however try with the ''options API" as seen in the lcjs-vue-template however I had the same issue.

Comment: Any chance you could make a fork of the lcjs-vue-template repository, reproduce there and share? I could then debug on the side of LCJS to see if it would give any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crash seems to be caused by Vue. More specifically this happens if LightningChart JS chart instance is placed to a Vue `ref`. To resolve this issue use `shallowRef` instead.

`const chart = shallowRef();`

https://codepen.io/snekw/pen/podmPjQ